# Awk to skip CSV rows with second field blank

Tags: csv, awk

I have a 16GB CSV that is ;-seperated and the fields are always quoted. I need to quickly filter out rows where the second field is blank.

```
"12345";"987";"..." # keep it
"67890";"";"..."    # omit it
```

The first two fields are numbers only, if that matters for performance.

I figure, that awk might be the most performant tool for this but I can't seem to get it right. I tried this, but it omits most lines wrongly:

```
cat huge.csv | awk '/^"\d+";"\d/' > filtered.csv
```

Of course it doesn't have to be awk; any command line tool commonly found on linux and OS X will do.

Comment: The `cat` is not really needed, this would be equivalent: `awk '/^"\d+";"\d/' huge.csv > filtered.csv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution simply using

```
awk -F\" '$4'
```

i.e., your command would be:

```
awk -F\" '$4' huge.csv > filtered.csv
```

This sets the input field separator to `"` and checks the 4th field. If it's non-zero it prints the line implicitly. Gives:

```
"12345";"987";"..." # keep it
```

tested with GNU awk 3.1.6

Comment: cool practical trick, I often use similar tricks in my one-liners. (It doesn't help against quoted quotes(`\"`) though)

Comment: @Nya Yes, it is a specific solution to the problem and the data presented, agreed. FWIW, I tried your approach first, but by the time I got the quoting/escaped quoting working you had already posted yours :)

Comment: All solutions took similarly long. I like the simplicity of your's.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `awk -v 'FS=;' '$2 != "\"\""' huge.csv > filtered.csv`

**Explanation**:
awk splits files into records(default: separated by newline character), and records are splitted into records(default: by whitespaces).

`-v` option allows to set any awk variable before running the script, and `FS` variable is special builtin, which specifies regex for fields separator. Then the script just looks at second field(which is second csv field), and if it's non-empty, it (implicitly) prints the whole record.

PS: Even though your script is non-idiomatic, it is almost correct: the regex should be: `/^"[^"]*";"\d/`, so it matches a line when first field is non-numeric.

PPS: If you need to filter lines by a given regex, use unix utility `grep`: `grep '^"[^"]*";"[0-9]' huge.csv > filtered.csv`

Comment: Instead of `-v` just use `-F ';'`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know that `;` never appears in any quoted field, you cannot use awk for this.  If that criterion is met, however, you can do:

```
awk '$2 != "\"\""' FS=\; huge.csv > filtered.csv
```

It might be a bit cleaner to write this as:

```
awk -F\; '$2 !~ /^""$/' huge.csv > filtered.csv
```

Comment: Techically speaking, awk is turing-complete language, so you can use it. Practically, if you use gawk(which is most commonly used nowadays), you may set `FPAT` variable to FPAT=\"[^"]*\", but that's won't help against quoted quotes `\"`

Comment: @Nya: `FPAT` requires gawk 4.